# Python implementation for WorkEtc. API

Tags: python

I've found [this](http://support.worketc.com/Community/Forums?Topic=711) post on the Work Etc. forums for a Python REST client and the forum used didn't include the indentation for the code nor did the author include them, so what I've done is input what I believe to be the correct indentation and have gotten the following:

```
import sys, json, urllib
from httplib2 import Http

class WORKetcRESTClient():
    session_key = None
    connector_hash = None

    def __init__(self,url):
        if not "http://" in url and not "https://" in url:
            url = "http://%s" % url
            self.base_url = url
        else:
            self.base_url = url

    def authenticate(self,user,password):
        args = { "email" : user,"pass" : password,}
        res = self.request("AuthenticateWebSafe", args)

        if res["Code"] == 1:
            self.session_key = res["SessionKey"]
            self.user = res["User"]
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def request(self,service,args):
        url = "%s/%s" % (self.base_url, service)
        if not self.session_key is None:
            url = "%s?VeetroSession=%s" %(url,self.session_key)
        p = {}
        p['data'] = json.dumps(args)
        h = Http()
        r,c = h.request(url, body=json.dumps(args), method="POST", headers = {'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
        if r.status == 200:
            jsondata = json.loads(c)
            return jsondata
        else:
            print r,c
            return {}

client = WORKetcRESTClient('http://company.worketc.com')
client.authenticate('User@company.com', 'pAsSwOrD')
result = client.request('FindCompanies',{'keywords':'customer'})
print result
```

To be 100% honest, if this were to run without any errors, I'm not sure what I would get printed to the console, but the errors I'm getting are keeping me from finding out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "worketc.py", line 42, in <module>

  File "worketc.py", line 17, in authenticate
    res = self.request("AuthenticateWebSafe", args)
  File "worketc.py", line 34, in request
    if r.status == 200:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
```

It's telling me that the variable 'r' is getting called before it is assigned/created, but I'm not sure where it needs to be created, or moved to, considering it's location in the current script. Can anybody shed some light onto this?

Comment: *Comment from [serg553](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3442593/serg553):* Thanks for this very nice snippet. I was wondering have you managed to fix it by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

```
   if not self.session_key is None:
        url = "%s?VeetroSession=%s" %(url,self.session_key)
   p = {}
   p['data'] = json.dumps(args)
   h = Http()
   r,c = h.request(url, body=json.dumps(args), method="POST", headers = {'contentType' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
```

is the correct indentation

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested and it gets past the error from before, now I'm getting a new error pointing to line 19: if res["Code"] == 1:    KeyError: 'Code'    What does that mean?

Comment: I think it means the authenticate url is not returning a json object ... or at least one that doesnt have "Code" as a key.. I would try printing `jsondata`(or even just `c`) in the `self.request` method and also print something when the code is not 200 so you know you have had an error